# Filter for multiple years Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df where I would like to filter for multiple years Pandas

**Data**

```
id type stat  date
aa ss   y     2022-01-01
bb tt   y     2023-01-05
cc uu   n     2023-01-05
aa hi   y     2021-01-01
aa hi   n     2021-02-01
```

**Desired**

```
id type stat  date
aa ss   y     2022-01-01
bb tt   y     2023-01-05
cc uu   n     2023-01-05
```

I wish to retrieve years 2022 and 2023.

**Doing**

```
df = df[df['date'].dt.year == 2022 & 2023]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

coerce to datetime and filter by dt.year

```
df[pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.year.isin([2022,2023])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also check `between`

```
df[df.date.between('2022-01-01','2024-01-01')]
   id type stat       date
0  aa   ss    y 2022-01-01
1  bb   tt    y 2023-01-05
2  cc   uu    n 2023-01-05
```